# Connectedness of stabilizer of regular element

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex simple Lie algebra and $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ be a regular element, i.e. its centralizer is of minimal dimension.

Consider the adjoint action of the adjoint group $G$ (with trivial center) on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

Is it true that the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$ is always connected?

If $x$ is semisimple, then it is known that the stabilizer of $x$ in the simply connected group is connected (see the book of Collingwood-McGovern, Theorem 2.3.3), and so by projection, also in the adjoint group.

If $x$ is regular and nilpotent (also called principal nilpotent), then one can check in the lists of all Lie algebras in the book of Collingwood-McGovern to check that the stabilizer is connected.

But what about a general regular element?
And if it is true, is there a simple proof (without using the classification of simple Lie algebras)?

Comment: I don't know what is the adjoint group.. can I assume $G$ is a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be it's Lie algebra??

Comment: At least this is true in $\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbf{C})$, without assuming regular. Indeed, for $x\in\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbf{C})$, the centralizer $C_x$ of $x$ in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ is connected (centralizers in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ are connected, and this applies to $x+t$ for suitable scalar $t$). Hence the centralizer $C_x/\mathbf{C}^*$ of $x$ in $\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ is connected. (On the other hand, in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{C})$ there are regular elements inside the group itself, with non-connected centralizer.)

Comment: The centraliser of an arbitrary element is the centraliser in the centraliser of the semisimple part, of the (regular there) nilpotent part.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: the adjoint group $G$ is the unique Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ which is centerless. If the centralizer is connected in a covering space, of course it is also connected in the adjoint group, but the converse is of course not true.

Comment: By the way, your argument in the semisimple case doesn't work:  it is true that the image in the adjoint group of the centraliser in the semisimple group is connected, but the centraliser in the adjoint group can, a priori, be strictly larger.  (This happens with @YCor's example of $g = \begin{pmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{pmatrix}$, whose centraliser in $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb C)$ is bigger than the image of its centraliser in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$; but that's on the group side.)  The conclusion is still true (in characteristic 0), just not the proof.

Comment: (For "semisimple group" in [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343059/connectedness-of-stabilizer-of-regular-element#comment857556_343059) read "simply connected group".)  So I should also have said that I disagree with [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343059/connectedness-of-stabilizer-of-regular-element#comment857554_343059):  an element (at least on the group level, if not, in characteristic 0, on the Lie-algebra level) can have connected centraliser in the simply connected, but not the adjoint, group.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\semi{_{\text{semi}}}\def\nil{_{\text{nil}}}$This is just an elaboration of [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343059/connectedness-of-stabilizer-of-regular-element/343094#comment857545_343059).  If $X \in \mathfrak g$ is regular, with semisimple part $X\semi$ and nilpotent part $X\nil$, then $X\nil$ is regular nilpotent in $\operatorname{Lie}(\operatorname C_G(X\semi))$, so you have said that you already know that $\operatorname C_{\operatorname C_G(X\semi)^\circ}(X\nil)$ is connected.  On the other hand, $\operatorname C_G(X\semi)$ is connected.  (Your argument for this by reduction to the simply connected case doesn't work, but it *is* true in general, in characteristic 0 or even just in not-too-small positive characteristic.  The reference that I know is Section 7 of [Yu - Construction of tame supercuspidal representations](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2001-14-03/S0894-0347-01-00363-0), although that's clearly the wrong place to look for general questions of this sort; better to look in Steinberg.  (Probably there's a precise reference in Collingwood–McGovern; the "simple connectedness implies connectedness" result you cite, which is valid on the group as well as the Lie-algebra level, is due to Steinberg.)  Thus, $\operatorname C_{\operatorname C_G(X\semi)^\circ}(X\nil)$, which we have seen is connected, equals $\operatorname C_{\operatorname C_G(X\semi)}(X\nil) = \operatorname C_G(X)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I felt that one should be able to reduce to the nilpotent case. But still, is there a direct argument without using the classification of Lie algebras?

Comment: @AThomas, I almost never think of centralisers of nilpotents, so I don't know off the top of my head; but I'll think about it.